# Given 2 points (x,y -> latitude and longitude), find the Trip whose origin and destiny is closer - 2D Tree

Tags: data-structures, tree, time-complexity, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Essentially I have an AVL of Trips (each node has, among other things, a Map of TripPhases - essentially data regarding the trip on each of its timestamps. 2 of the attributes are Latitude and Longitude).

Given 2 points: Origin and Destiny (express as Latitude and Longitude) - let's call it P1, P2 - I have to find the trip whose beginning and end is the closest to those 2 points.

To solve this I created 2 2D Trees. The first contains the origin Phases of a given Trip and the second, the destiny Phase.

I know that if I was given only 1 point it would be easy, just a matter of implementing the nearestNeighbour method. With 2 points it's trickier though, as the origin of 1 Trip might be closer the the 1st point, but its destiny might be completely far off.

So my idea would be to create 2 TreeMaps -> one for the origin coordinates of each trip and the other one for the destiny coordinates. The key of the TreeMap would be the distance.

After that I would have to calculate the absolute value of the difference in distance between the keys of the 2 TreeMaps (for the same Trip).

However, this doesn't sound very efficient when it comes to Big O.

Is there a better approach?

Thanks